# How to wrap between letter and punctuation to avoid extra blank space in the end of line?

Tags: css

The first box has an annoying blank in the end of its first line. The second box works fine.

I think CSS try to avoid punctuation to appear in the beginning of one line. But it results ugly topography.

How can I force it to wrap?

```css
.box {
  margin: 2em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  width: 8em;
  height: 8em;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.text {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p class="text">你好，我来自中国！！！你好，我来自中国！</p>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <p class="text">你好，我来自中国你好，我来自中国</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Unclear what you’re asking; what do you _want_ the result to look like? What do you want to “force to wrap”, and where?

Comment: @wang try to give    `text-align: justify` for the class `text`

Comment: @Webruster The `justify` works not that good for this case, I want exactly aligned just like the second box.

Comment: @CBroe Please notice the extra space in the end of the 1st line of the first box, I want to eliminate that space, and make the text aligned to such an extent that it looks like a two dimensional matrix.

Comment: @wangzhihao will this work [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kri4shna/akf2rwg8/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're writing Chinese, I guess `word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-all;` will serve the purpose:

```css
.box {
  margin: 2em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  width: 8em;
  height: 8em;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.text {
  font-size: 1em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p class="text">你好，我来自中国！！！你好，我来自中国！</p>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <p class="text">你好，我来自中国你好，我来自中国</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah I forgot Chrome. Check it again I fixed.

Comment: Why need `white-space: pre` for chrome?